# Collections.sort() throws compile time error for Generic List

Tags: java

Why this code is throwing compile time error?

```
interface Pair<K, V> extends Comparable<OrderedPair<K, V>> {
    K getKey();

    V getValue();
}


class OrderedPair<K, V> implements Pair<K, V> {

    private K k;
    private V v;

    public OrderedPair(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return k;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderedPair o) {
        return this.getKey().toString().compareTo(o.getKey().toString());
    }
}


public class Operation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList() {{
            add(new OrderedPair("BCA", "29"));
            add(new OrderedPair("CAB", "31"));
            add(new OrderedPair("ABC", "30"));
        }};
        Collections.sort(list); // showing compile time error

    }
}
```

Comment: After your edit, your code is just wrong - I guess the type was removed due to the `<>` so ignore my previous comment. Your current code says that a `Pair` can only be compared to an **`OrderedPair`** so when you give `sort` a `List<Pair<...>>` it doesn't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you are trying to implement a Data structure `Pair` which you'd like to store in a list and later sort using `Collections.sort` based on the keys of `Pair`

The problem in your code is that you are using `Collections.sort` which accepts `List<T> list` where T extends `Comparable<? super T>`. Basically what this means is `Collections.sort` Accepts T that extends itself.

i.e. in your case You should extend `Comparable` with `Pair` instead of `OrderedPair<String,String>`. You can additionally change the interface to Abstract class and implement `compareTo` in `Pair` class itself. Here is a code with slight modifications to your code.

```
abstract class Pair<K, V> implements Comparable<Pair> {
    abstract K getKey();

    abstract V getValue();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return this.getKey().toString().compareTo(o.getKey().toString());
    }
}


class OrderedPair<K, V> extends Pair<K, V> {

    private K k;
    private V v;

    public OrderedPair(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return k;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return v;
    }
}


class Operation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList() {{
            add(new OrderedPair("BCA", "29"));
            add(new OrderedPair("CAB", "31"));
            add(new OrderedPair("ABC", "30"));
        }};
        Collections.sort(list); // showing compile time error

    }
}
```

Try this :)

Comment: No need for the `abstract class` - use a `default` method. You also haven't fixed the rawtypes in the example code.

Comment: Yes we could have default method in the interface too. But since we are trying to make a data structure here. I thought it would be the best to have an abstract class.  Solving the raw types is not a part of the problem. I wanted to make least changes to make the answer easy to understand.

Comment: On the one hand you changed the OPs `interface` to an `abstract class` and on the other hand you didn't fix the obvious errors on the grounds that you don't want to change things?